# SQL group by value depending on an interval given by the min and max of a date field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have following table given:

```
----------------------------     
| x    |  y   | date       |
----------------------------
| 1    | 1    | 01.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 02.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 03.01.2000 |
| 1    | 2    | 04.01.2000 |
| 1    | 2    | 05.01.2000 |
| 1    | 2    | 06.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 07.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 08.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 09.01.2000 |
----------------------------
```

Now i need to group the table depending on both `y` and `x` values, depending on the resulting interval given by the `date` column:

```
-----------------------------------------     
| x    |  y   |  min       | max        |
-----------------------------------------
| 1    | 1    | 01.01.2000 | 03.01.2000 |
| 1    | 2    | 04.01.2000 | 06.01.2000 |
| 1    | 1    | 07.01.2000 | 09.01.2000 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Just grouping `y` will result in a wrong result, since there is the possibility that the `y` value switches back to a previous state as stated in the example.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a gap, e.g. the row `1     2     05.01.2000` missing? And what's the expected result then? If you want two result rows @Serg's answer is correct (and some nice explaination of how it works can be found here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167068/2639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
select x,y, min(dat), max(dat)
from (
    select x,y, dat, row_number() over(order by dat) - row_number() over(partition by x, y order by dat) as grp
    from mytable 
)
group by x,y, grp
order by  min(dat), x,y
```

This is an old trick, `row_number( ..)-row_number(partition..)` keeps the same value till partitioned data do not change and changes the value when `x,y` change. So with `x,y`  this computed `grp` identifies every group of the same `x,y`.

Comment: You should add some explanation, this is hard to understand :-)

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: This technique is known as [tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html)

Comment: @Boneist thanks for the tabibitosan reference. Really Oracle has ROW_NUMBER() and other analytic function at least since 8i (1998).   I belive there should be an older example somewhere.

Comment: @Serg: Analytical Functions have been introduced in Oracle 9i 2001.

Comment: @Serg the tabibitosan is an ancient (Japanese, I think) technique, and I first came across it via Aketi Jyuuzou [back in 2011.](https://community.oracle.com/message/3991678) But the aim of my original comment was to provide more information to you and the OP, not to find the earliest possible example (I'm not sure why you think we need earlier examples?)

Comment: @Boneist , I appretiate  the reference, and as it's history related in a way, just added some retro perspective. The trick is really old one, I agree.